# randcase weight behaviour unexpected

Tags: system-verilog

```
class test1;

  function test_randcase();
    for (int idx=0; idx < 10; idx++) begin
      randcase
      50: begin
            $display("displaying from first cases");
          end
      50: begin
            $display("displaying from second case");
          end
      endcase
    end      
  endfunction
endclass

program main;
  initial begin
    test1 t1=new();
    t1.test_randcase();      
  end
endprogram
```

Since each case is equally weighed here (50/100=0.5) so the expectation is that I would see each display 5 times in total. However, I see "first case" print 6 times and "second case" print 4 times. If this is the behavior of randcase, then how would I achieve my intention of equal weight? I used vcs compiler for this execution.

output:

```
displaying from second case
displaying from first cases
displaying from first cases
displaying from first cases
displaying from first cases
displaying from second case
displaying from first cases
displaying from second case
displaying from second case
displaying from first cases
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at this problem another way, suppose you had to choose a completely random 10-bit number where each bit has a 50% chance of being 0 or 1. There are 1024 possible numbers with a 1/1024 chance of having 10 1's and a 1/1024 chance of having 10 0's. And the odds of choosing a number with exactly 5 1's and 5 0's is around 25%. If you run more iterations, your `randcase` distribution would approach 0.50, but the odds of getting an *exact* 0.5 distribution diminish.

If your requirement is getting an *exact* distribution, you need to know upfront how many iterations you plan to have. There are several approaches you could take, one of which I can show you

```
class test1;
  enum {FIRST, SECOND} itor[10];
  function new;
    itor[0:4] = '{5{FIRST}};
    itor[5:9] = '{5{SECOND}};
  endfunction
  function void test_randcase();
    itor.shuffle();
    foreach(itor[i]) begin
      case(itor[i])
      FIRST: begin
            $display("displaying from first cases");
          end
      SECOND: begin
            $display("displaying from second case");
          end
      endcase
    end      
  endfunction
endclass

module main;
  test1 t1=new();
  initial repeat(10)begin
    $display("---");
    t1.test_randcase();      
  end
endmodule
```

Other ways are shown in my paper from DVCon 2020, [SystemVerilog Constraints: Appreciating What You Forgot in School to Get Better Results](https://resources.sw.siemens.com/en-US/white-paper-systemverilog-constraints-appreciating-what-you-forgot-in-school-to-get)